# UITextField in storyboard controller stops working in iOS6

Tags: uitextfield, ios6, xcode-storyboard

We have a storyboard controller displaying a map. The screen has many nested views to display the search text, maps and other selection criteria for the map. This controller works fine for 5.0/5.1 but when I ran it in the 6.0 simulator, the search text field stopped responding (no cursor blink or keyboard popup). To resolve the problem I tried approaches such as app delegate method call on makeKeyWindowVisible, resignFirstResponder method call in text delegate callback, etc. I then tried removing controls from the view and reconstructing them. None of these approaches worked. Finally I detached the segue to the controller and reattached it, when it mysteriously worked. There is no explanation for this solution but it works!